# JAX-RS: How to define response type using query parameter instead of Accept header?

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, restlet, resteasy

In JAX-RS is there any way to define response type using query parameters instead of Accept header (e.g. `/api/foo?format=json`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways to do content negotiation in JAX-RS: based on URL, based on Accept header and based on request parameter. Please check out link [Content Negotiation Based on Request Parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/WINK/jax-rs-content-negotiation.html). It contains sample code how to do content negotiation on request parameter. The link is for Apache Wink project, but the code should work in Jersey implementation.

Comment: rest-easy also has this feature http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.5.Final/userguide/html/JAX-RS_Content_Negotiation.html#param_media_mappings

Comment: @kiran.kumarM even better! I'm using rest-easy! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a built-in way to do it based on a query parameter, but the [UriConnegFilter](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/UriConnegFilter.html) supports the suggested method of using a URI suffix, like `/api/foo.json`. Maybe you could conform to that convention? If not, the UriConnegFilter would be a good starting place for building your own support for using query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to enable one switch in web.xml like below

```
   <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.media.type.param.mapping</param-name>
    <param-value>format</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

/api/foo?format=json